# Why was string as pointer or string as raw array always called as pointer in overloaded function?

Tags: c++, string

I have a function `check_str` that is overloaded for `const char*` and `const char(&)[N]` types.

```cpp
void check_str(const char*) {
    std::cout << "string as pointer!!" << '\n';
}

template <size_t N>
void check_str(const char(&)[N]) {
    std::cout << "string as array!!" << '\n';
}
```

Then, I declared `arr_01` as `const char[]`:

```cpp
const char arr_01[] = "Desmond";
```

When I call them:

```cpp
check_str("Desmond");
check_str(arr_01);
```

The first call prints `"string as pointer!!"` while the second call still prints `"string as pointer!!"`.

Well, if I use `std::string` or `std::string_view`, it will lose the point of classifying them.

Is there a way to call the overloaded function that has the argument type `const char(&)[N]` for `arr_01` in order to print `"string as array!!"` without specifying the non-type template parameter?

Comment: Just use `std::array` instead of plain arrays in the first place?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, but there is no initializer for strings in `std::array`

Comment: Favoring non-templates over templates is how overload resolution works. So for these two overload? No way to change the chosen one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::array`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

template <std::size_t sz>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto to_array(char const (&cstr)[sz]) noexcept {
  std::array<char, sz> std_arr;
  std::copy_n(cstr, sz, std_arr.data());
  return std_arr;
}

void check_str(char const*) { 
  std::puts("string as pointer!!"); 
}

template <size_t N>
void check_str(std::array<char, N> const&) {
  std::puts("string as array!!");
}

int main() {
  auto constexpr arr = to_array("Desmond");
  check_str("Desmond");
  check_str(arr);
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7xe8vP1fb)

Comment: what about for raw arrays (char), do they always need to be converted into `std::array` to call the second overloaded function?

Comment: @DesmondGold yes. Consider only using `std::array` and not using raw arrays. I only use `std::array` or `std::vector` depending on if the size is known at compile time and I never have issues with array to pointer decay, etc.

Comment: Also consider `std::string`, which is fairly suitable for specifically handling string data.

Comment: @Eljay yes exactly, `std::string` for strings and `std::vector` for everything else if it's dynamic. `std::array` for static allocations.